# How to save taken image only into a folder, not DCIM folder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-capture

I have a problem with the following script. It is saving the image in the folder i want it to but it is also saving it to DCIM folder, thing that i don't want. So what do i have to change to save it **only** into my folder?

**

- *save photo*

**

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
        // Environment.getDataDirectory()(Environment.)
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/Android/data/com.itbstudios.shoppinglist/Shopping List");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".itb");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

**

- *take photo*

**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, as I know it's not saving to DCIM folder, but it will apear in gallery app. Gallery app scanning all files to find media files. To prevent your folder of scanning, you must add empty file with name .nomedia to you folder.

Comment: Never hardcode paths. Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, please.

Comment: ok, i'll keep in mind

Comment: mmno i still can see it in gallery and at details is dcim/100media/img001.itb TESTED ON Htc ONE s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy: Capture the photo as described in the question, save it into the internal memory (data/data/com.package...) After that delete it from the public folder (DCIM/MEDIA/100MEDIA) with the following method (delete last taken picture from that folder...):

```
private void deleteLastPhotoTaken() {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE };

    final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, 
            null,null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + "DESC");

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int column_index_data =  
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        String image_path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        File file = new File(image_path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try it soon and after i'll be back with the result :)

Comment: looks like is crushing on query

Comment: fixed the crash and it deletes the file but in the gallery is still an inaccesable file which is described as being in DCIM

Comment: I just wanted to know what "DESC" means in getContentResolver().query()... It has to replaced with something else? Because leaving it just like this, I get "column date_takenDesc does not exists" error in the cursor... Thank you!

Comment: Good one , i had to use the same strategy